# Stat a PID for claim time?

Tags: process, c, proc

Is it possible to `stat` a process ID to get the time it was claimed?

Comment: What do you mean by "time it was claimed"?

Comment: Like when a program started to use it last. Like if it was reused then what time it was taken by that next program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can look at the `cmdline` or `exe` associated with the PID:

```
# stat /proc/2529/{exe,cmdline}
  File: ‘/proc/2529/exe’ -> ‘/bin/bash’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 16136       Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-09-26 07:46:05.435479000 +0530
Modify: 2014-09-26 07:41:05.447479000 +0530
Change: 2014-09-26 07:41:05.447479000 +0530
 Birth: -
  File: ‘/proc/2529/cmdline’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 16117       Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-09-26 07:41:05.447479000 +0530
Modify: 2014-09-26 07:41:05.447479000 +0530
Change: 2014-09-26 07:41:05.447479000 +0530
 Birth: -
```

I have used the [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/stat.1.html) command, but I don't think the [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/stat.2.html) function would respond differently when applied to these files.

---

An example:

Save this as `test.c`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat stats;
    char exe_path[32] = "/proc/";
    char cmdline_path[32] = "/proc/";
    char *exe = "/exe", *cmdline = "/cmdline";

    if (argc < 2)
        return -1;
    if (lstat (strcat (strcat (exe_path, argv[1]), exe), &stats) != -1)
    {
        printf("exe: %s\n%s%s%s", exe_path, ctime (&stats.st_atime), ctime (&stats.st_mtime), ctime (&stats.st_ctime));
    }
    else perror ("stat error: ");
    if (lstat (strcat (strcat (cmdline_path, argv[1]), cmdline), &stats) != -1)
    {
        printf("cmdline: %s\n%s%s%s\n", cmdline_path, ctime (&stats.st_atime), ctime (&stats.st_mtime), ctime (&stats.st_ctime));
    }
    else perror ("stat error: ");

    return 0;
}
```

Testing it out:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ ./test $$               
exe: /proc/1811/exe
Fri Sep 26 09:02:59 2014
Fri Sep 26 09:02:59 2014
Fri Sep 26 09:02:59 2014
cmdline: /proc/1811/cmdline
Fri Sep 26 09:02:59 2014
Fri Sep 26 09:02:59 2014
Fri Sep 26 09:02:59 2014

$ date
Fri Sep 26 09:34:03 IST 2014
```

The `cmd` stats maybe more reliable.

Comment: Thanks muru! This is `stat`'ing a file though no? :( In this case there is an executable launched with command line arguments to create multiple instances. So I can't stat the executable it will give me info on a wrong instance no?

Comment: Holllllly shucks!!! I just did a `stat "/proc/PID_HERE/exe" and it worked you're right, Im not so good at reading c yet :P Thanks man thanks thanks thakns!!!! Can you please verify that it will be different even if its single exe being run with command lin args, i also noticed that `birth` is blank. This is image i got for 2 firefox profiles: ![](http://i.imgur.com/4AsauWc.png)

Comment: @Noitidart you should use `lstat` as the `exe` files are links to the executables. Then you'll get different results.